# Using GDB to trace guest OS inside a hypervisor, the whole running on Qemu - kvm

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoint, qemu, hypervisor

I use Gdb to trace the execution (breakpoint, single stepping, ...) of a hypervisor OS in Qemu and it works fine so far.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -display sdl -cpu host -serial my: stdio -m 8192 --bios ../../tool/boot/tianocore.bin -drive format = raw, file = var / run /hypervisor.img -machine q35 -s -S
gdb path/to/hypervisor
target remote: 1234
```

Now, I need to trace the execution of a guest OS in the hypervisor, all run by Qemu. And it does not work.
Yet I added the debugging symbols files related to the OS and I also modified the architecture of the instructions.

```
add-symbol-file ~ / Tinycore / vmlinux 0x100000
add-symbol-file bin / munich 0x18000
set architecture i386: x64_32 // because the guest OS is compiled in 32 bits
```

But when execution passes the instructions vmresume, vmlauch and continues in the guest OS, Gdb gets confused, single-stepping does not work anymore and breakpoints end up at uncertain addresses.
Does anyone have an idea of ​​what I missed?
Or is it really impossible?
Is there another way to achieved this?
The hypervisor I'm working on is [Genode](https://github.com/genodelabs/genode) and the guest OS is T[inycore Linux](http://tinycorelinux.net/10.x/x86/release/src/kernel/).

---

1. [munich](http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/~kauer/oslo/) is a 32 bits bootloader used to boot the Tinycore Linux.
2. hypervisor, vmlinux and munich are the binaries compiled with debugging symbols.